# How to make map work asynchronously using Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I want to make map run asynchronously. I tried using async and Promise.all but I not sure where I am going wrong. This is code I have written

```
// this is the id => [1,2,3] and total of each => [2, 3, 2]
useEffect(()=> {
  countNumFunc(idList)
})

const countNumFunc = (idlist) => {
  let count = 0
  Promise.all(idList.map(async (id) => {
    console.log("id = ", id)
    getInfoFromDb(id).then((res) => {
      if(res.data) {
        count = count + res.data.total
        console.log("Count = ", res.data.total)
      }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("error = ", error)
    })
  }))
  console.log("Count total = ", count)
}
```

Here the output should have been:

```
id = 1
Count = 2
id = 2
Count = 5
id = 3
Count = 7
Count total = 7
```

But the output is:

```
id = 1
id = 2
id = 3
Count total = 0
Count = 2
Count = 3
Count = 2
```

Comment: `Promise.all(() => {.......}).then(() => console.log(count))`

Comment: Btw.  You should be expecting,  `id = 1, id = 2, id = 3, count = 2, count = 3, count = 2, Count total = 7`  If not you don't want to be using `Promise.all`

Comment: Oh and finally `getInfoFromDb(id)`  make sure you return the Promise, or Promise.all() will return instantly anyway -> `return getInfoFromDb(id)`

Comment: @Keith I don't want it be be displayed like this: id = 1, id = 2, id = 3, count = 2, count = 3, count = 2, Count total = 7. At first, I had not used promise.all but just map with async but that was not working as required. I basically want everything in the code to be executed line by line

Comment: Yes, ideally you want to use `async / await`, as @trincot has shown.

Comment: @Keith Yeah I'll checked it with async/await. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired result you should:

- not use `Promise.all`: `Promise.all` is when you want to create all promises first and then await them. But from your desired output it shows you want to create the promises (do the DB queries) one by one, each time waiting for the previous one to resolve.
- not use `.map()`. First of all, `.map()` returns an array. If you have no use for that array, then don't use `.map()`. Secondly, `.map()` will make all iterations synchronously -- it doesn't help to make its callback `async`.

Instead declare `countNumFunc` as an async function, loop with `for..of`, and `await` the value that `getInfoFromDb(id)` will resolve to.

Secondly, you seem to want to show a *running* count, so then you should not display `res.data.total`, but just `count`:

```js
// Mock:
const getInfoFromDb = async (i) => ({ data: {total: [0, 2, 3, 2][i]} });

const countNumFunc = async (idList) => {
  let count = 0
  for (let id of idList) {
    console.log("id = ", id)
    const res = await getInfoFromDb(id);
    if(res.data) {
        count = count + res.data.total
        console.log("Count = ", count)
    }
  }
  console.log("Count total = ", count)
} 

countNumFunc([1,2,3])
```